# Mongoose find null response

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I try to make a get request on `/movies/{movieId}` route to get a movie info and I get an empty array.

I have used `findOne()` function and I have the get the same empty array.

When I use as path `/movies` works fine and I can get all the movies that I have inside my database.

**app.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const mongoose = require ('mongoose');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
require('dotenv/config');

app.use(bodyParser.json());

//Import routes
const postsRoute = require('./routes/posts');
const moviesRoute = require('./routes/movies');


app.use('/posts', postsRoute);
app.use('/movies', moviesRoute);

//Middlewares
app.use('/posts', () =>{
    console.log('This is a middleware running');
})

//ROUTES
app.get('/', (req, res) =>{
    res.send('We are on home');
})

//Connect to database
mongoose.connect(
    process.env.DB_CONNECTION,
 { useNewUrlParser: true }, () =>{
    console.log('Connected to the database!');
})

//How to start listen from server
app.listen(3000);
```

**route for movies**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const Movie = require('../models/Movies');

//GET BACK ALL THE MOVIES
router.get('/', async (req, res) =>{
    try{
        const movies = await Movie.find();
        res.json(movies);
    }catch(err){
        res.json({message : err});
    }
})

//SUBMIT A MOVIE
router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    const movie = new Movie({
        movieId: req.body.movieId,
        tittle: req.body.title,
        genres: req.body.genres
    });
    try{
    const savedMovie = await movie.save();
    res.json(savedMovie);
    }catch(err){
        res.json({message: err});
    }
}); 

//SPECIFIC MOVIE
router.get('/:movieId', async (req, res) =>{
    try{
    const movie = await Movie.find({ movieId: req.params.movieId }).exec();
    console.log(req.params.movieId);
    console.log(movie);
    res.json(movie);
    }catch(err){
        res.json({message: err});
    }
});


module.exports = router;
```

**movies model**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');


const MovieSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    
    movieId:  Number,
        
    title:  String,
        
    genres: String
        
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Movies', MovieSchema);
```

Comment: Are you sure your `req.params.movieId` exists into DB?

Comment: Yes exists into the database.

Comment: i think it's because req.params.movieId is a string, try converting to number

Comment: I change the hole database. Because i had import files from csv all types was strings and inside my model schema was number.

Answer (score 0):

It's not correct to use two GET methods for one route and Express will not recognize this and it's only able to define the first GET method you written !
so, in your code as "/" and "/:movieId" are both routes for "/" , Only the first one will work.

**Solution:**
In your moviesRoute Use only one route and use both logics in that one:

```
router.get('/:movieId', async (req, res) =>{
    try{
        let {movieId} = req.params;

        if(typeof movieId === 'undefined'){
            // if user just send request to "/movies" path
            const movies = await Movie.find();
            res.json(movies);
        }
        else{
            // if user asked for specific movie id like "/movies/{id}"
            const movie = await Movie.find({movieId}).exec();
            console.log(req.params.movieId);
            console.log(movie);
            res.json(movie);
        }
    }
    catch(err){
        res.json({message: err});
    }
});
```

Comment: Everything ok. The csv that i add on my database have numbers as string and only need to change the type of my schema data.

Answer (score 0):

you should convert movieId to a number, do like this:

```
router.get('/:movieId', async (req, res) =>{
    try{
    const movie = await Movie.find({ movieId: +req.params.movieId }).exec();
    console.log(req.params.movieId);
    console.log(movie);
    res.json(movie);
    }catch(err){
        res.json({message: err});
    }
});
```